# Is there a more efficient way of returning records that match the max value?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with fields of interest:

```
Order      Shift    DateTime
23605624   Red      43470.23958
23605624   Yellow   43469.73958
23605624   Green    43469.38542
23605917   Red      43471.26042
23605917   Green    43471.73958
23605953   Red      43470.23958
23605953   Yellow   43469.17083
```

I want [Order] and [Shift] where [DateTime] is the largest value for each [Order].  So the above table would translate to:

```
Order      Shift    DateTime
23605624   Red      43470.23958
23605917   Green    43471.73958
23605953   Red      43470.23958
```

Though I don't need the DateTime field.

I have actually achieved this but the method feels overly convoluted (and takes a considerable time for the query to run)  I have subqueries in both the from clause and one of the joins.

It feels like I should be able to do some kind of join in the where clause along the lines of "value=max(value) but I just can't seem to figure it out as the subquery already has a join and also includes a case statement and I can't seem to master the syntax.

This is the complete code I have:

```
SELECT
   max_datetime.[Order],
   max_datetime.[Line],
   max_datetime.[Quantity],
   max_datetime.[UoM],
   shifts.[Shift]

FROM (
   SELECT
      SCMPEH.PRONUM as [Order],
      SCMPEH.LINNUM as [Line],
      SUM(SCMPEH.PEHQTY) as [Quantity],
      SCMPEH.PEHUNT as [UoM],

      MAX(CASE
         WHEN SCMPEH.PEHSTT < '05:45:00'
         THEN SCMPEH.PEHDAT + SCMPEH.PEHSTT + 1
         ELSE SCMPEH.PEHDAT + SCMPEH.PEHSTT
      END) as [DateTime]

   FROM
      SCMPEH

      INNER JOIN SCMLIN on
         (SCMLIN.LINNUM = SCMPEH.LINNUM)

      INNER JOIN SCMSHI on
         (SCMSHI.SHINUM = SCMPEH.SHINUM)

   WHERE (
      SCMPEH.PEHDAT >= '1/1/2019'
   ) AND (
      SCMLIN.LINEXP = 'Y'
   )

   GROUP BY
      SCMPEH.LINNUM,
      SCMPEH.PRONUM,
      SCMPEH.PEHUNT

   ) as max_datetime

INNER JOIN (
   SELECT
      SCMPEH.PRONUM as [Order],
      SCMSHI.SHIDES as [Shift],

      CASE
         WHEN SCMPEH.PEHSTT < '05:45:00'
         THEN SCMPEH.PEHDAT + SCMPEH.PEHSTT + 1
         ELSE SCMPEH.PEHDAT + SCMPEH.PEHSTT
      END as [DateTime]

   FROM
      SCMPEH

      INNER JOIN SCMSHI on
         (SCMSHI.SHINUM = SCMPEH.SHINUM)

   WHERE (
      SCMPEH.PEHDAT >= '1/1/2019'
   )
   ) as shifts on
   (shifts.[Order] = max_datetime.[Order]) AND
   (shifts.[DateTime] = max_datetime.[DateTime])
```

What I'm most interested in is the [Shift] field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to use `WITH TIES` in concert with `row_number()`

**Example**

```
Select top 1 with ties * 
 From  YourTable
 Order By Row_Number() over (Partition By [Order] Order By DateTime desc)
```

**Returns**

```
Order       Shift   DateTime
23605624    Red     43470.23958
23605917    Green   43471.73958
23605953    Red     43470.23958
```

**Full Disclosure**:  Using a sub-query with row_number() is a nudge more performant